# CSS3 :not() selector Issue with child elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a problem deselecting the child element using css3 :not selector.

I have a p element containing span as child and sub child with an anchor element. I want to make the opacity of the texts containing inside the p excluding any anchor elements.

What am I doing wrong here?

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato);

a {
  color: #fde217;
}

.contactinfo-wrap {
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px;
  font-family: Lato;
  background-color: #00254a;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 30px;
}

.contactinfo-wrap p:not(a) {
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: .6;
}


.contactinfo-wrap p:not(strong) {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="contactinfo-wrap">
  <p><strong><span class="details">Postal Address</span></strong></p>
  <p>
    <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-lg"></i></span>
    <span class="details">PO Box 35142 Collins Street West<br>
         120 King Street, Melbourne<br>
         Victoria 2000 Australia</span></p>
  <p class="phone">
    <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-phone fa-lg"></i></span>
    <span class="details">+60 0 0000 0000</span></p>
  <p>
    <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg"></i></span>
    <span class="details"><a href="mailto:yourname@domain.com">yourname@domain.com</a></span>
  </p>

</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to deselect an element based on its children?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is what you want: http://codepen.io/lizardhr/pen/eZOwZM

Remember that CSS is a cascading style sheets which describe what style is needed for each element listed in a markup language like HTML.

All elements style described after others take effects and the styles before it are discarded so if an element like your `<strong>` and `<a>` tags need a different style of the containing element, e.g. your `.contactinfo-wrap <div>` you need to style them after it.

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato);

.contactinfo-wrap {
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px;
  font-family: Lato;
  background-color: #00254a;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 30px;
}

.contactinfo-wrap p {
  color: #ffffff;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
  /* opacity: .6; */
}


strong {
  color: inherit; /* put the style you want here */
}

a {
  color: #fde217;
}
```

Comment: Hah. very strange how can i forget that there is an option for rgba. Didn't realized about that. Thanks for the input. @lizardhr

Answer (score 2):

`p:not(a)` means "An element that is a `p` but which is not an `a`" (which is *all* `p` elements).

There is no way in CSS to select an element based on features of its descendants.

Your best bet would be to preprocess the HTML (in a programming language) and add `class` attributes to the paragraphs you wanted to match.

Comment: Isn't there any other solution rather than having a p elements with a specific class.

Comment: @Maqk — I can't think of any that are simpler or easier.

Answer (score 1):

avoiding :not selector,
an alternative could be using rgba to color your font:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato);
 a {
  color: #fde217;
}
.contactinfo-wrap {
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px;
  font-family: Lato;
  background-color: #00254a;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 30px;
}
.contactinfo-wrap p {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}
.contactinfo-wrap strong {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
.contactinfo-wrap a {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="contactinfo-wrap">
  <p><strong><span class="details">Postal Address</span></strong>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-lg"></i></span>
    <span class="details">PO Box 35142 Collins Street West<br>
         120 King Street, Melbourne<br>
         Victoria 2000 Australia</span>
  </p>
  <p class="phone">
    <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-phone fa-lg"></i></span>
    <span class="details">+60 0 0000 0000</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg"></i></span>
    <span class="details"><a href="mailto:yourname@domain.com">yourname@domain.com</a></span>
  </p>

</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

You are missing a space in your selector:

```
.contactinfo-wrap p :not(a) {}
```

This selects all child elements inside the `<p>` which are not an anchor.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato);

a {
  color: #fde217;
}

.contactinfo-wrap {
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px;
  font-family: Lato;
  background-color: #00254a;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 30px;
}

.contactinfo-wrap p :not(a) {
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: .6;
}


.contactinfo-wrap p :not(strong) {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="contactinfo-wrap">
  <p><strong><span class="details">Postal Address</span></strong></p>
  <p>
    <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-lg"></i></span>
    <span class="details">PO Box 35142 Collins Street West<br>
         120 King Street, Melbourne<br>
         Victoria 2000 Australia</span></p>
  <p class="phone">
    <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-phone fa-lg"></i></span>
    <span class="details">+60 0 0000 0000</span></p>
  <p>
    <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg"></i></span>
    <span class="details"><a href="mailto:yourname@domain.com">yourname@domain.com</a></span>
  </p>

</div>
```

Comment: That won't work. The goal is to select the paragraphs that don't contain links. This will select every element inside a paragraph that isn't a link, which will make everything translucent (because none of the links are children of the paragraphs, only deeper descendants).

Comment: That's not really clear from the question. My interpretation was, OP wants to make every text inside the paragraphs semi-transparent with the exception of anchor tags.

Comment: Then this answer still won't do the job because you are making the span elements which *contain* the anchors translucent (which affects all the descendants).

Comment: Sure, I was just pointing out the (to me obvious) error of the missing space. Of course, the selector needs to be more precise. Maybe OP can say, if my interpretation is off, then I can delete the answer to not mislead others.